# Unable to connect to external network service from docker running inside github actions workflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I am building a docker compose based micro-service and am trying to execute integration tests from within github actions. Tests all pass locally and the app is currently deployed and working. However when I run the app in GHA it appears that the chat service is unable to reach the twitch irc servers. The strangest part is the chat service is capable of logging in but apparently not sending messages. I can only assume I am missing some critical network configuration in my compose file.
I am running the following compose file in GHA, any ideas folks?

```
# docker-compose.gha.yml
# Copyright (C) 2023
# Squidpie

version: "3.5"
services:
    redis-test:
        build:
            context: ${STRAUSS_ROOT_DIR}
            dockerfile: ${STRAUSS_ROOT_DIR}/tests/redis/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - strauss
        depends_on:
            - redis

    chat-test:
        build:
            context: ${STRAUSS_ROOT_DIR}
            dockerfile: ${STRAUSS_ROOT_DIR}/tests/chat/Dockerfile
        networks:
            - strauss
        depends_on:
            - chat

    redis:
        image: redis:7.0.6-alpine
        container_name: redis
        networks:
            - strauss

    chat:
        image: strauss/chat:${STRAUSS_CHAT_PKG_VERSION}
        container_name: chat
        build:
            context: ${STRAUSS_ROOT_DIR}
            dockerfile: ${STRAUSS_ROOT_DIR}/services/chat/Dockerfile
            args:
                version: "prod"
                STRAUSS_BUILD_DIR: ${STRAUSS_BUILD_DIR}        
        environment:
            TWITCH_USER: ${TWITCH_USER}
            TWITCH_TOKEN: ${TWITCH_TOKEN}
        networks:
            - strauss
        volumes:
            - ./strauss.yml:/strauss/strauss.yml
        depends_on:
            - redis

networks:
    strauss:
        name: strauss
        driver: bridge
```

With the following Github Action Workflow:

```
# strauss-validate.yml
# Copyright (C) 2023
# Squidpie

name: strauss-validate
run-name: ${{ github.actor }} is validating strauss
on:
  push:
    branches:
      [dev, stage/*]
  pull_request:
    types: [assigned, opened, synchronize, reopened]
    branches:
      [dev]
  workflow_dispatch: {}

jobs:
  validate:
    name: Validate strauss
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    env:
      STRAUSS_ROOT_DIR: ${{ github.workspace }}
      STRAUSS_BUILD_DIR: target/debug
      
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup GitVersion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/setup@v0.9.15
        with:
          versionSpec: '5.x'

      - name: Resolve Version
        id: gitversion
        uses: gittools/actions/gitversion/execute@v0.9.15
      
      - name: Setup Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '3.2'
          bundler-cache: true

      - name: Setup Strauss Env
        run: |
            ./scripts/gen-gha-env.sh
            cat .env > .env.runtime
            echo ${{ secrets.STRAUSS_SECRETS }} >> .env.runtime
            printf '%b\n' "services:\n    chat:\n        channel: <test channel>\n" > strauss.yml

      - uses: actions/cache@v3
        id: cache-rust
        with:
            path: |
                ~/.cargo/bin/
                ~/.cargo/registry/index/
                ~/.cargo/registry/cache/
                ~/.cargo/git/db/
                target/
            key: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('**/Cargo.lock') }}

      - name: Build & Unit Test Services
        run: docker compose --env-file .env -f strauss-build.debug.yml run build
      
      - name: Run Integration Tests
        run: |
            docker compose --env-file .env.runtime \
                -f docker-compose.gha.yml \
                up -d

      - name: Get Test Status
        run: |
            sleep 45
            docker logs `docker container ls -a | grep chat-test | awk '{print $1}'` | grep "PASSED" && \
            docker logs `docker container ls -a | grep redis-test | awk '{print $1}'` | grep "PASSED"

      - name: Inspect Dockers
        if: failure()
        run: |
            docker inspect `docker container ls -a | grep "strauss/chat" | awk '{print $1}'`
            docker inspect `docker container ls -a | grep "redis:7" | awk '{print $1}'`
            docker inspect `docker container ls -a | grep "chat-test" | awk '{print $1}'`
            docker inspect `docker container ls -a | grep "redis-test" | awk '{print $1}'`
      
      - name: Collect Docker Logs
        if: failure()
        uses: jwalton/gh-docker-logs@v2.2.1
```

Comment: Can you please share more details on this "chat service is unable to reach the twitch irc servers" : what error do you see in logs, what does this service do?

Comment: the chat service is very simple, listens to twitch chat and transports messages to the redis pubsub network, likewise it listens on a redis pubsub channel and transports those messages to twitch chat. There are no connection errors in the logs, the chat service is able to login successfully. The redis test is able to pass and the chat test is able connect to the redis network and send a message, but then nothing happens. Nothing interesting prints to the docker logs and the docker inspect doesn't show anything out of the ordinary. very confused.

Comment: It seems that you need to narrow down your use case to debug this efficiently.

Comment: Create a super simple image that connects directly to twitch without any redis an whatever other dependencies, log both before, after and catch, add here some details of what this image is doing.